# Multiline text underline with paddings and 100% width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an underlined multiline text that should like on the image below:
[image]

text-decoration doesn't work in the way I need - I need a line of 100% width and paddings on the left and right. I have  tried to use inline text and bottom border but in that case I can't set the width and paddings. I have also tried to use a background image - but this does not look like a flexible solution - I have to make an image for each font-size to repeat it vertically.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. (edited) - Guess I'm wrong. Take a look at the solution below!

Comment: No idea why you got downvoted, it's an interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of only one way to do that and it's described in this article by Chris Coyier @ CSS-Tricks

[**Fun with Line-Height**](https://css-tricks.com/fun-line-height/)

It depends on a known line-height and a repeating background gradient.

**SCSS**

```
$lh: 1em;

.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
}



.wrapper {
  line-height: $lh;
  padding: $lh*2;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(black, 0)   0,
    rgba(black, 0)   $lh/1em*16px-1,
    rgba(black, 0.5) $lh/1em*16px-1,
    rgba(black, 0.5) $lh/1em*16px
  );
}
```

This is the output CSS with a line-height of 1em.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
.wrapper {
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 2em;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0, transparent 15px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 15px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 16px);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0, transparent 15px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 15px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 16px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis, magni, sint. Saepe sunt quia praesentium explicabo dolore consectetur impedit quidem! Repellat ut nihil neque cumque. Quasi neque consequatur dicta voluptatum vel, sint perspiciatis
    tenetur. Sit harum, fugiat, nesciunt quos, sequi asperiores cum recusandae iste autem nobis illum, nihil perferendis earum!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: A little improvement to use the same colour as the text:


`background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
to bottom,
transparent 0,
transparent $lh/16px * 16px-1,
currentColor $lh/16px * 16px-1,
currentColor $lh/16px * 16px
);`

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand i would use this css method for inline block.

```
 a {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 }
  a::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 1em;
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
 margin-top: 5px;
 }
```